# Where on Earth did that image wander off to?

Tags: discussion, meta

Yesterday, I was on Meta and saw an answer posted yesterday that included a ridiculously humorous image going over rules of English grammar. Yet I forgot to favorite the question, and now I can't seem to find that answer again. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44900/why-has-no-one-realized-unicorns-have-wings).

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for that too.

Comment: I can't see that Image. Can you please show that?